# Not able to suppress the output in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am using following code to perform an operation. But everytime "ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)" is getting printed on the console. I dont want this to be printed on the console and rather it should be suppressed. How to achieve it?
code:

```
LDAP_CONF="/etc/opt/nokia/ldapserver.conf"
bindError="ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)"
basedn=`cat $LDAP_CONF | grep basedn | cut -d " " -f2`
verify=`su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D 

"uid=$userName,ou=people,ou=accounts,$basedn" -w $newPswd"`

if echo "$verify" | grep -q "$bindError"; then
    printPasswdLog "${ERR}" "bind to ldap server failed"
else
    printPasswdLog "${INF}" "bind to ldap server Successful for $userName "
fi
```

I am getting the below output:

ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
Wed Jun  3 12:45:56 EEST 2015| INFO  | bind to ldap server Successful for nwi3system

Comment: `basedn=\`cat $LDAP_CONF | grep basedn | cut -d " " -f2\`` is better written as `basedn=$(grep based $LDAP_CONFIG) | cut -d" " -f2`.  See also http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to suppress all error messages, just put this at the start of the script:

```
exec 2> /dev/null
```

But you really don't want to do that.  It's probably sufficient to do:

```
verify=$(su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D 

uid=$userName,ou=people,ou=accounts,$basedn -w $newPswd" 2> /dev/null)
```

but you don't want to do that either.  Why do you want to throw away a perfectly good error message to replace it with one that contains less information?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect your error to some other file or to `/dev/null`. You can use this way

```
./SCRIPT 2> /dev/null
```

This will redirect error to /dev/null and no record will be of error.

Instead better will be to record it somewhere. Try this

```
./SCRIPT 2>> error.txt
```

This will create a file and all errors will be recorded there.